# How to find where the controller action is called ? Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I can see that there is a controller
with `saveitemAction()`

```
/app/code/local/Web/Popup/controllers/IndexController.php
```

How do i find from where this controller action is called ?
i.e (saveitemAction())

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to check your **route** name for the extension Web/Popup

route name available in the file etc/config.xml

your actual action is like {routename}/index/saveitem

you can search this action in the full extension directory